# After migrating library to scalajs, publish-local does not work

Tags: scala, cross-compiling, scala.js

Following the hints of the post explaining the [basics of migrating to scalajs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143126/how-do-i-port-an-existing-scala-library-to-scalajs) and [this page](https://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/0.6.16/#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject) about [cross-compilations](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/cross-build.html), I decided to add cross compilation to my standalone dependency-free scala library by doing the following changes:

- I added a file `project/plugins.sbt` with the content
  `addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.16")`
- I added `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"` in `build.sbt` because else just `scalaVersion` was using `2.10`

I also added in the `build.sbt` the following content to ensure that I can keep the same directory structure, since I don't have any particular files for the JVM or for Javascript:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).
  aggregate(fooJS, fooJVM).
  settings(
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {}
  )

lazy val foo = crossProject.crossType(CrossType.Pure).in(file(".")).
  settings(version := "0.1").
  jvmSettings(
    // Add JVM-specific settings here
  ).
  jsSettings(
    // Add JS-specific settings here
  )

lazy val fooJVM = foo.jvm
lazy val fooJS = foo.js
```

But now, after I published the project locally using `sbt publish-local` the projects depending on this library do not work anymore, i.e. they don't see the classes that this library was offering and raise errors.
I looked into `.ivy2/local/.../foo/0.1/jars` and the JAR went from 1MB to 1KB, so the errors make sense.

However, how can I make sure the JVM jar file is compiled correctly?

**Further informations**

The jar time does not change anymore, it looks like there had been some miscompilation. I deleted the `.ivy2` cache, but now `sbt publish-local` always finishes with success but does not regenerate the files.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution myself.

I needed to remove the `publishLocal := {}` from the build, and now all the projects depending on my library work fine.